# Approaches for migrating .csv files stored in S3 to DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

We have a hundreds of thousands of .csv files stored in S3 that contain at least several data records each. (each record is its own row)

I am trying to design a migration strategy to transform all the records in the .csv files and put them into DynamoDB. During the migration, I'd also like to ensure that if any new .csv gets added to the S3 bucket, we automatically trigger a lambda or something to do the transformation and write to DynamoDB as well.

Eventually we'd stop writing to S3 entirely, but initially we need to keep those writes and any writes to S3 to also trigger a write to DynamoDB. Does anyone know of any good strategies for doing this? (Is there something like DynamoDB streams except for S3?) Any strategies for getting the existing things in .csv in S3 over to DynamoDB in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS has many tools you can use to solve this problem. Here are a few.

1. You could use [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/). It supports migrating data [from S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.S3.html) and [into DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.html). This AWS product is designed specifically for your use case, and it handles pretty much everything.

   > Once the migration has started, DMS manages all the complexities of the migration process including automatically replicating data changes that occur in the source database during the migration process.
2. S3 can [publish events to trigger a lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) which can be used to continuously replicate the data to DynamoDB.
3. [AWS Data Pipelines](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline) basically does batch ETL jobs, which could move your data all at once from S3 to DynamoDB. You might also be able to run periodic sync jobs if you can tolerate a delay in replicating data to DynamoDB.
4. [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) can crawl your data, process it, and store it in another location. I think it would provide you with an initial load plus the ongoing replication. While it could work, it’s designed more for unstructured data, and you have CSV files which are usually structured.

I’d recommend using AWS Database Migration Service because it’s the one-stop solution, but if you can’t use it for some reason, there are other options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if DynamoDB has "load records from CSV" feature (RedShift does).

If it does not, then you could roll your own.  Write a Python function that imports the `csv` and `boto3` modules, takes as input an S3 path (inside an event dictionary).  The function would them download the file from S3 to temp dir, parse it with `csv`, then use boto3 to insert into DynamoDB.

To get the history loaded, write a function that uses `boto3' to read the list of objects in S3, then call the first function to upload to DynamoDB.

To get future files loaded, install the first function as a Lambda function, and add a trigger from S3 Object Creation events to run the function whenever a new object is put onto S3.